# How do I refresh View in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, view, swiftui

I have an app with log in screen. It has to 3 tabs. Once the app loads it loads a log in tab. But once the credentials are hit and the if statement turns to true it doesn't show the other tabs. I would like to know how to refresh the view once the conditional turns to true.

ViewConsole

```
import SwiftUI

var verify = false

struct ViewConsole: View {
    var body: some View {
        if verify == true {
            TabView{
                ContentView()
                    .tabItem {
                        Label("Names", systemImage: "person.3")
                    }
                
                AdminView()
                    .tabItem{
                        Label("Admin", systemImage: "gear")
                    }
            }
        } else {
            LoginView()
                .tabItem{
                    Label("Log In", systemImage: "key")
                }
        }
    }
}

struct ViewConsole_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ViewConsole()
            .environmentObject(Admin())
    }
}
```

App Delegate

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct Work_Tracker_For_KumonApp: App {
    @StateObject var admin = Admin()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {

            ViewConsole()
                .environmentObject(admin)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need `verify` to be an `@State` property of your view and pass it as a binding to your `LoginView`.  Once the login view updates it to true, magic happens :)

Comment: But it doesn't let me make it a global variable. "Property wrappers are not yet supported in top-level code" `@State private var verify: Bool = false`

Comment: It shouldn't be a global variable.  **Never** use global variables.  It should be a property of `ViewConsole` and pass it to an `@Binding` in `LoginView`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't going to want `verify` to be a global variable. One way to do it would be to add a `@State` property to your `ViewConsole`. To have access to it in your `LoginView`, you can pass a Binding to it using the `$` symbol.

```
struct ViewConsole: View {
    @State private var verify = false
    
    var body: some View {
        if verify {
            TabView {
                Text("Content")
                    .tabItem {
                        Label("Names", systemImage:
                                "person.3")
                    }
                Text("Admin")
                    .tabItem{
                        Label("Admin", systemImage:
                                "gear")
                    }
            }
        } else {
            LoginView(verify: $verify)
                .tabItem{
                    Label("Log In", systemImage:
                            "key")
                }
        }
        
    }
}

struct LoginView : View {
    @Binding var verify : Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            verify = true
        }) {
            Text("Verify")
        }
    }
}
```

A second way to approach this would be to use an `ObservableObject` with a `@Published` property. It looks like you already have one called `Admin` set up as a `environmentObject`. It might look something like this:

```
class Admin : ObservableObject {
    @Published var loggedIn = false
}

struct ViewConsole: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var admin : Admin
    
    var body: some View {
        if admin.loggedIn {
            TabView {
                Text("Content")
                    .tabItem {
                        Label("Names", systemImage:
                                "person.3")
                    }
                Text("Admin")
                    .tabItem{
                        Label("Admin", systemImage:
                                "gear")
                    }
            }
        } else {
            LoginView()
                .tabItem{
                    Label("Log In", systemImage:
                            "key")
                }
        }
        
    }
}

struct LoginView : View {
    @EnvironmentObject var admin : Admin

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            admin.loggedIn = true
        }) {
            Text("Verify")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do place in the parameters for the preview code? `struct LoginView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        LoginView()
    }
}
}`. it passes an error

Comment: If you're talking about my second example, you'd need to attached `.environmentObject(Admin())` to the `LoginView()` in the preview. You also have an extra `}` in that code.

Comment: Im talking about the first one its says "Missing argument for parameter 'verify' in call"

Comment: In my first example, `LoginView` doesn't take an admin parameter, so I wonder if something got changed. But the error is telling you to add a parameter, like this `admin: Admin()` But, again, I'm not seeing where that could be in my code, so it might be something that got changed as you added it to your codebase.

Comment: I made a typo I meant to say. "Missing argument for parameter 'verify' in call" for the first on and I didnt add any code

Comment: `LoginView(verify: .constant(false))` I assumed it had been edited because I didn't have `admin` there, but the `verify` one makes sense.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67187386/how-do-i-change-the-json-file-in-the-app-in-swiftui