# How do I change the JSON File in the app in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I been trying to open two different json files when needed. But when I load the first one and then reset and tiger select the new JSON it doesn't change when open it doesn't change to the new JSON file. I tried using a binding but then I get an error in my preview struct. `verify` is another binding variable I have thats why its in the preview struct.

Basically the login screen has a picker. and the user chooses what center they want. once they select a center it maps to the selected JSON first time but once they log out and select the second center it doesn't change the JSON file to the new center

```
import SwiftUI

var appName: String = "Work Tracker"
var centers = ["Center", "Center1", "Center2"]
var center = ""


struct LoginView: View {
    
    @State private var LoginChecker: Double = 0
    @State private var selectedCenter = ""
    
    let verticalPaddingForForm = 40.0
    var body: some View {
                
                VStack{
                    Button(action: {
                        
                        centerPicker()
                        print(selectedCenter)
                        print(center)

                        
                    }){
                        if LoginChecker == 0{
                            Text("Login")
                                .font(.system(size: 20))
                                .foregroundColor(Color.init("primaryText"))
                                .bold()
                                .frame(width: 120.0, height: 50.0)
                                .background(Color.init("primaryTextField"))
                                .cornerRadius(20)
                            
                            
                            
                            
                            
                            
                            
                        }else if LoginChecker == 1{
                            VStack(alignment: .center) {
                                
                                Text("Invalid Login. Please Try Again")
                                    .font(.system(size: 20))
                                    .padding()
                                    .foregroundColor(Color.init("primaryTextField"))
                                
                                Text("Login")
                                    .font(.system(size: 20))
                                    .foregroundColor(Color.init("primaryText"))
                                    .bold()
                                    .frame(width: 120.0, height: 50.0)
                                    .background(Color.init("primaryTextField"))
                                    .cornerRadius(20)
                                
                                
                                
                            }
                        }
                        
                        
                    }
                    .font(.system(size: 100))
                    .padding()
                    .animation(.easeOut(duration: 0.5))
                    
                }
                
                

                
                Section{
                
                Picker("Center:", selection: $selectedCenter) {
                    ForEach(centers, id: \.self) {
                        Text($0)
                    }.foregroundColor(Color.init("primaryTextField"))
                    
                }
                
                
                }
                .padding(.bottom, -100.0)
                .frame(width: 1.0, height: 1.0)
               // .foregroundColor(Color.init("primaryTextField"))
               // .background(Color.init("primaryTextField"))
                
               
                
                
                
                
            }.padding(.horizontal, CGFloat(verticalPaddingForForm))
        }
        
        
    };

struct LoginView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            LoginView(verify: .constant(false))
            //      .previewLayout(.fixed(width: 1700, height: 1100))
            
        }
    }
```

```
    func centerPicker(){
        if selectedCenter == "Center1"{
            center = "Center1.json"
            appName = "Center1"
        }else if selectedCenter == "Center2"{
            center = "Center2.json"
            appName = "Center2"
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not totally clear on what the question is or what is going on here, but if you want your view to respond somehow to `center`, it needs to be a `@State` variable as well.

Comment: I made it `@Binding var center: String`. But it is throwing out errors in my other login view where `verify` is "Missing argument for parameter 'center' in call"

Comment: And plus it needs to be a global variable.

Comment: Basically the login screen has a picker. and the user chooses what center they want. once they select a center it maps to the selected JSON  first time but once they log out and select the second center it doesn't change the JSON file to the new center.

Comment: You should show enough in your question to reproduce the problem. Clearly, this isn't enough. If something says "missing argument for parameter `center`", then you should provide an argument for it... I guarantee it does not in fact need to be a global variable.

Comment: there is too much of code I will have to share the project...

Comment: You could write a small program that tries to do what you want https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example